# Hover over image, display text & opacity change

Tags: html, css, opacity

I'm trying to work on a piece of code now. The hope is that hovering over the image changes the opacity and also makes some text visible within it.

The getting the image to change opacity is easy, but it's just getting my head around having the text display that is causing the issue.

My HTML at the moment -

```css
.WhyAGradeNotes {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-image: url("http://www.placehold.it/250x300");
}

.WhyAGradeNotes p {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.WhyAGradeNotes:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  .WhyAGradeNotes p {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
    <section class = "WhyAGrade">
      <span class = "WhyAGradeNotes"><p>Revision Notes</p></span>
      <span class = "WhyAGradeSample"></span>
    </section>
```

As you can see, I'm having difficulty. What I'm guessing is that it has to do with the visibility states, but I just can't figure out how to have it working properly

Comment: `<span>` element cannot contain block level elements like `<p>`. you might want to rethink your structure.

Comment: Probably a stupid question, but why? It seems to be working. What are the potential issues that I could run in to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this below code

```css
.WhyAGradeNotes {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 150px;
 margin-right: 150px;
 height: 300px;
 width: 250px;
 background-image: url("http://www.placehold.it/250x300");
}
.WhyAGradeNotes p {
 visibility: hidden;
}
.WhyAGradeNotes:hover {
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.WhyAGradeNotes:hover p {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section class = "WhyAGrade"> 
    <span class = "WhyAGradeNotes">
      <p>Revision Notes</p>
    </span> 
    <span class = "WhyAGradeSample"></span> 
</section>
```

Comment: Perfect, that got it working! Will mark it as the answer when I'm able to!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are missing a `}` after `opacity:0.5;`. You also have an extra `}` at the end of your CSS. Unless you are using a preprocessor, but even then your syntax would be incorrect.

Secondly, you need to set `visibility: visible` on the `p` only when `.WhyAGradeNotes` is hovered.

```css
.WhyAGradeNotes {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 150px;
  margin-right: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  background-image: url("http://www.placehold.it/250x300");
}
.WhyAGradeNotes p {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.WhyAGradeNotes:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.WhyAGradeNotes:hover p {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<section class="WhyAGrade">


  <span class="WhyAGradeNotes"><p>Revision Notes</p></span>
  <span class="WhyAGradeSample"></span>


</section>
```

Comment: Yea, I had a feeling that I had gotten it wrong. I had actually been trying to do a nested attribute on the hover, but couldn't think of the proper way of doing it. This is working too, but the other person just got in first.

Answer (score 1):

Can use pseudo-classes for this case:

`.WhyAGradeNotes:hover p`.

that code tells when `.WhyAGradeNotes:hover` any `p` inside `.WhyAGradeNotes` will be visible. In case you want only direct `p` is visible you can change it to `.WhyAGradeNotes:hover>p`

try this one:

```css
.WhyAGradeNotes
{
display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    height: 300px; 
 width:250px;
 background-image: url("http://www.placehold.it/250x300");
}

.WhyAGradeNotes p
{
visibility:hidden;
}
.WhyAGradeNotes:hover
{
opacity:0.5;
  }
.WhyAGradeNotes:hover p
{
visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<section class = "WhyAGrade">


<span class = "WhyAGradeNotes"><p>Revision Notes</p></span>
<span class = "WhyAGradeSample"></span>


</section>
```

for complete list please check this [W3Schools CSS Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.WhyAGradeNotes
{
display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    height: 300px; 
 width:250px;
 background-image: url("http://www.placehold.it/250x300");
}

.WhyAGradeNotes p
{
visibility:hidden;
}
.WhyAGradeNotes:hover p
{
opacity:0.5;

visibility:visible;

}
```

```html
<section class = "WhyAGrade">


<span class = "WhyAGradeNotes"><p>Revision Notes</p></span>
<span class = "WhyAGradeSample"></span>


</section>
```